# Inserting XML data into database failing

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I'm having an issue with trying to insert my XML data into my database. I've spent the past two days researching on google but I'm still struggling. If anyone could help that would be most appreciated. Thank you very much.

I get the following error messages when I try to insert the data:

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in
>   insert_into_database.php on line 13
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function item() on null in
>   insert_into_database.php on line 13

insert_into_database.php

```
<?php

$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=data', 'root', '');

$xmldoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmldoc->load('data.xml');

$xmldata = $xmldoc->getElementsByTagName('group');
$xmlcount = $xmldata->length;

for ($i=0; $i < $xmlcount; $i++) {
    $id = $xmldata->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('id')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $group = $xmldata->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('group')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $category = $xmldata->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('category')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $question = $xmldata->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('question')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $a = $xmldata->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('a')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $b = $xmldata->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('b')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $c = $xmldata->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('c')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $d = $xmldata->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('d')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $stmt = $db->prepare("insert into xml values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
    $stmt->bindParam(1,$group);
    $stmt->bindParam(2,$category);
    $stmt->bindParam(3,$question);
    $stmt->bindParam(4,$a);
    $stmt->bindParam(5,$b);
    $stmt->bindParam(6,$c);
    $stmt->bindParam(7,$d);
    $stmt->execute();
    printf($name.'<br />');
}

?>
```

data.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<questions>
<group name="Question Group 1">
    <id>1</id>
    <category>Category A</category>
    <question name="Question 1" a="Answer 1" b="Answer 2" c="Answer 3" d="Answer 4"/>
    <question name="Question 2" a="Answer 1" b="Answer 2" c="Answer 3" d="Answer 4"/>
    <question name="Question 3" a="Answer 1" b="Answer 2" c="Answer 3" d="Answer 4"/>
    <question name="Question 4" a="Answer 1" b="Answer 2" c="Answer 3" d="Answer 4"/>
    <question name="Question 5" a="Answer 1" b="Answer 2" c="Answer 3" d="Answer 4"/>
</group>
<group name="Question Group 2">
    <id>2</id>
    <category>Category B</category>
    <question name="Question 1" a="Answer 1" b="Answer 2" c="Answer 3" d="Answer 4"/>
    <question name="Question 2" a="Answer 1" b="Answer 2" c="Answer 3" d="Answer 4"/>
    <question name="Question 3" a="Answer 1" b="Answer 2" c="Answer 3" d="Answer 4"/>
    <question name="Question 4" a="Answer 1" b="Answer 2" c="Answer 3" d="Answer 4"/>
    <question name="Question 5" a="Answer 1" b="Answer 2" c="Answer 3" d="Answer 4"/>
</group>
<group name="Question Group 3">
    <id>3</id>
    <category>Category C</category>
    <question name="Question 1" a="Answer 1" b="Answer 2" c="Answer 3" d="Answer 4"/>
    <question name="Question 2" a="Answer 1" b="Answer 2" c="Answer 3" d="Answer 4"/>
    <question name="Question 3" a="Answer 1" b="Answer 2" c="Answer 3" d="Answer 4"/>
    <question name="Question 4" a="Answer 1" b="Answer 2" c="Answer 3" d="Answer 4"/>
    <question name="Question 5" a="Answer 1" b="Answer 2" c="Answer 3" d="Answer 4"/>
</group>
</questions>
```

Comment: Can you isolate the errored line? it makes it a little easier to follow

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure how to isolate the line sorry, but line 13 is "$group = $xmldata->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('group')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;"

Comment: It seems to my like this `$xmldoc->load('data.xml');` or `$xmldata = $xmldoc->getElementsByTagName('group');` is failing can you echo them before the loop to see if they have values?

Comment: I get the following error message, "Catchable fatal error: Object of class DOMDocument could not be converted to string in insert_into_database.php on line 6" I've submitted the code to http://pastebin.com/ZkUP4pHL sorry I've been up two days straight, hope I didn't make a mistake there

Comment: In case of *question* attributes, what value(s) you want to extract?

Comment: You can't echo the DomDocument object, that is what giving you the error on line 6. So remove the echo statement

Comment: Your insert isn't failing. Your DOM operations are failing. That error has NOTHING to do with pdo/mysql.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to get the *group*, then do this:

```
$group = $xmldata->item($i)->getAttribute('name');
```

Overall, you need to change your code like this:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=data', 'root', '');

$xmldoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmldoc->load('data.xml');

$xmldata = $xmldoc->getElementsByTagName('group');
$xmlcount = $xmldata->length;

for($i = 0; $i < $xmlcount; ++$i){
    $id = $xmldata->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('id')->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $group = $xmldata->item($i)->getAttribute('name');
    $category = $xmldata->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('category')->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $questioncount = $xmldata->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('question')->length;

    for($j = 0; $j < $questioncount; ++$j){
        $question = $xmldata->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('question')->item($j)->getAttribute('name');
        $a = $xmldata->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('question')->item($j)->getAttribute('a');
        $b = $xmldata->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('question')->item($j)->getAttribute('b');
        $c = $xmldata->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('question')->item($j)->getAttribute('c');
        $d = $xmldata->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('question')->item($j)->getAttribute('d');

        // Do your database operations

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using MySQL's [`LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-xml.html) command for bulk import of XML document. This avoids any looping. However, the structure must adhere to following types:

```
<row column1="value1" column2="value2" .../>

<row>
  <column1>value1</column1>
  <column2>value2</column2>
</row>

<row>
  <field name='column1'>value1</field>
  <field name='column2'>value2</field>
</row>
```

Hence, consider also [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/Style/XSL/) (the transformation language to manipulate XML documents to various end use structures). Since most data resides in attributes, below XSLT (embedded as string but can be external file) transforms to first structure:

```
// LOAD XML AND XSL SOURCES
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load('data.xml');

$xsl = new DOMDocument;
$xslstr = '<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
            <xsl:output version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
            <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

              <xsl:template match="/questions">
                 <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="group"/>
                 </xsl:copy>
              </xsl:template>

              <xsl:template match="group">     
                 <xsl:apply-templates select="question"/>     
              </xsl:template>

              <xsl:template match="question"> 
               <xsl:copy>   
                   <xsl:attribute name="id"><xsl:value-of select="ancestor::group/id"/></xsl:attribute>
                   <xsl:attribute name="group"><xsl:value-of select="ancestor::group/@name"/></xsl:attribute>
                   <xsl:attribute name="category"><xsl:value-of select="ancestor::group/category"/></xsl:attribute>
                   <xsl:attribute name="question"><xsl:value-of select="@name"/></xsl:attribute>
                   <xsl:copy-of select="@a|@b|@c|@d"/>
               </xsl:copy>
              </xsl:template>    
            </xsl:transform>';

$xsl->loadXML($xslstr);

// CONFIGURE TRANSFORMER (ENABLE .php_xsl EXTENSION)
$proc = new XSLTProcessor;
$proc->importStyleSheet($xsl); 

// TRANSFORM SOURCE
$newXml = $proc->transformToXML($doc);

// SAVE TO FILE
$xmlfile = 'output.xml';
file_put_contents($xmlfile, $newXml);

// RUN MYSQL COMMAND (MAY NEED TO ALLOW --local-infile IN SETTINGS)
try {
   $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=data', 'root', ''); 
   $db->execute("LOAD XML DATA INFILE 'path/to/output.xml'
                 INTO TABLE xml
                 ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<question>';");
} catch(PDOException $e) {  
    echo $e->getMessage();  
}
```

Transformed XML *(attribute names must match database fields)*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<questions>
  <question id="1" group="Question Group 1" category="Category A" question="Question 1" a="Answer 1" b="Answer 2" c="Answer 3" d="Answer 4"/>
  <question id="1" group="Question Group 1" category="Category A" question="Question 2" a="Answer 1" b="Answer 2" c="Answer 3" d="Answer 4"/>
  <question id="1" group="Question Group 1" category="Category A" question="Question 3" a="Answer 1" b="Answer 2" c="Answer 3" d="Answer 4"/>
  <question id="1" group="Question Group 1" category="Category A" question="Question 4" a="Answer 1" b="Answer 2" c="Answer 3" d="Answer 4"/>
  <question id="1" group="Question Group 1" category="Category A" question="Question 5" a="Answer 1" b="Answer 2" c="Answer 3" d="Answer 4"/>
  <question id="2" group="Question Group 2" category="Category B" question="Question 1" a="Answer 1" b="Answer 2" c="Answer 3" d="Answer 4"/>
  <question id="2" group="Question Group 2" category="Category B" question="Question 2" a="Answer 1" b="Answer 2" c="Answer 3" d="Answer 4"/>
  <question id="2" group="Question Group 2" category="Category B" question="Question 3" a="Answer 1" b="Answer 2" c="Answer 3" d="Answer 4"/>
  <question id="2" group="Question Group 2" category="Category B" question="Question 4" a="Answer 1" b="Answer 2" c="Answer 3" d="Answer 4"/>
  <question id="2" group="Question Group 2" category="Category B" question="Question 5" a="Answer 1" b="Answer 2" c="Answer 3" d="Answer 4"/>
  <question id="3" group="Question Group 3" category="Category C" question="Question 1" a="Answer 1" b="Answer 2" c="Answer 3" d="Answer 4"/>
  <question id="3" group="Question Group 3" category="Category C" question="Question 2" a="Answer 1" b="Answer 2" c="Answer 3" d="Answer 4"/>
  <question id="3" group="Question Group 3" category="Category C" question="Question 3" a="Answer 1" b="Answer 2" c="Answer 3" d="Answer 4"/>
  <question id="3" group="Question Group 3" category="Category C" question="Question 4" a="Answer 1" b="Answer 2" c="Answer 3" d="Answer 4"/>
  <question id="3" group="Question Group 3" category="Category C" question="Question 5" a="Answer 1" b="Answer 2" c="Answer 3" d="Answer 4"/>
</questions>
```